# CSS- responsively centering logo in header with the name on it's sides

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I am having a hard time centering my logo on the center of my header. When displayed correctly it would look like this:  "Name" Logo "Surname"  .Being the logo at the center, and the "name" and "surname" displaying at both sides of it, "name" on it's left and "surname" on it's right. 
(You'll understand better with the picture I'm posting)

[Header: logo not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS8Jj.png)

So I would like the circled logo to be the center of the header, then have "Pousada" adapt to it at it's right and same with "Team" at it's left.

This is my CSS and HTML:

```css
*{
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 }

#rafa {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 40% 0;
  background-size:30%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
  border-top:none;
  
  }
  
  
#BJJ {
  text-align:center;
  height: 4rem;
  font-weight: normal;

 }
 
 
.escudo{
  text-align:center;
  
 
  }
  
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  
 }
  

 
#uno {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size: 2em;
  display:inline-block;
  }
 
#dos {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2em;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
 }

img {
  max-width: 15%;
  clear:both;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
 
  }
 
ul {
  color: #000;
  list-style: none;
  text-align:center;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid #000 1.5px;
  padding:0;
  height: 2.5em;
  border-top:none;
  
 
 }
 
li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border-right: 2px;
  }
  
#welcome{
  text-align:center;
 } 
/************ESTILO LINKS*************/
li a {
text-decoration:underline;
color: #000;
}

.Inicio {
color: #fff;
text-decoration:none;
 }

/*****************ARTE SOAVE*******************/

/*****************EL EQUIPO*******************/

/*****************LA ESCUELA*******************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <link href="Treehouse Programación/Recursos/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700|Roboto+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Pousada Team Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <header id="rafa">
 <a href="Pousada Team.html" class="Inicio">
   <h3 id="BJJ">Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu</h3>
   <div class="escudo group">
     <h3 id="uno">Pousada</h3>
        <img src="309011_3565552909659_642031164_n.jpg"/>
      <h3 id="dos">Team</h3>
   </div>
 </a> 
 </header>
 
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="Arte Soave.html">Arte soave</a></li>
     <li><a href="El Equipo.html">El Equipo</a></li>
  <li><a href="La Escuela.html">La Escuela</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
 
 <div id="welcome">
   <h3>Bienvenido al equipo</h3>
 </div>
 
 <div>
 </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried with float, but didn't do well with it. What I have tried here is to use inline-block to have the 3 elements of this  header ("Pousada", "logo" and "Team") align.

Any help with this particular problem I have and any content recommendations (or project practices) to fully understand HTML and CSS principles (like layouts and positioning) so I can learn them and move on to more functional aspects like Javascript, will be HUGELY appreciated, you can totally expect any help back that I can provide.

Thanks in advance, and if there's anything I can do to make this place better, please let me know.

Best regards,
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix for you:
I have added a background color to the div's to help you identify them.

HTML:
Add your header, add your logo inside the header... then add both the first and the last names inside of the logo div. By adding the names inside of the logo; when ever you move the logo the names will move relative to it.

```
<div class="Header">
  <div class="Logo">
    <div class="FirstName">FirstName</div>
    <div class="LastName">LastName</div>
  </div><!-- End CenterContent -->
</div><!-- End Header -->
```

CSS:
I use the single line method of writing my css.
You can easily adjust the dimensions of the logo DIV and you can move the names around as needed.

```
.Header{position:relative; width:100%; height:300px; display:block; float:left; background:SILVER;}
.Logo{position:relative; margin:auto; width:200px; height:200px; background:BLACK;}
.Logo > .FirstName{position:absolute; top:90px; left:-100px; min-width:1em; text-align:center;}
.Logo > .LastName{position:absolute; top:90px; right:-100px; min-width:1em; text-align:center;}
```

Your Welcome.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: However, what I meant for logo was the image I wanted to have on the centre. Maybe you took this into account in your answer and I didn't understand it, but I don't know where the image fits in the HTML you just wrote :S .  Thanks again, Miguel ;D.